# simple JavaScript alert wont display

Tags: javascript, html

every thing seams to work fine except my calculate function, the alert dose not display. i cant seem to under stand why.
if i remove all the code in the function except the first var and chat alert to alert(fname);  it will work.  but not when i add any of the other vars

```
<pre> <code>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>***********</title>


        <script type="text/javascript">



        function calculate(){

        var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
        var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
        var cyear = 2014;
        var yob = document.getElementById("yob").value;

        alert(fname+" "+lname+", this year you will be "
+(cyear - Number(yob)) + "years old!");

        }

        </script>   

        <style type="text/css"> 

        form {background-color:#B18CE8;
              width:500px;
              margin-top: 50px;
              margin-left: auto;
              margin-right:auto;
              font-family: Arial, sans-serif; padding: 20px;
              box-shadow:10px 10px #333333;
                    /*h-shadow(r) v-shadow(r) blur(o) spread(o) color(o) inset(o)*/
                    /*(r)means required attribute, (o) means optional attribute*/
            }
        fieldset {  border: none; border-radius:10%; background-color:#ffff19}
        fieldset legend {padding:5px; border-radius: 50%; background-color:#0099ff;}            

        .labelWidth100 {float:left; display:block; width:100px; clear:left;}            

        </style>

    </head> 
        <body onload="fname.focus();">
            <form>



                <fieldset style="width:450px"><legend>Name</legend>
                    <label for="fname" class="labelWidth100">First name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br><br>
                    <label for="lname" class="labelWidth100">Last name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><br><br>
                    <label for="yob" class="labelWidth100">Year of Birth:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="yob" id="yob"><br>
                </fieldset><br>


                <button type="button" onclick="calculate();">Calculate</button>

            </form>
            <br>

            <footer style="border:2px solid black; margin-left:0px; text-align:left;">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                document.write("This page was last modified: " + document.lastModified);
            </script>
            </footer><!--close footer-->


    </body>
</html> 

<pre> <code>
```

Comment: Do you have any JS errors when you look at the console?

Comment: [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging). You have no element with ID `lname`. See also [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element) (and yeah, you are missing parenthesis, which actually results in a syntax error, as you can see in the console).

Comment: Note `-` converts to number, so you don't need `Number`. And don't use `document.write`, see the warning in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#document.write%28%29), use DOM methods instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a missing parenthesis at the end:

```
alert(
    fname
    +" "
    +lname
    +", this year you will be "
    +(cyear - Number(yob))
    + "years old!"
); /* This closing parenthesis was missing!! */
```

Comment: even after adding ) it still will not display. i also changed the " "lname" so not it is pointing to the right text box. but the alert still wont display.  me editor is just notepad++

Comment: @user2951100 The editor is unrelated. If you open your browser's console, you will see where the error is.

Comment: i am not aware that notepadd++ has a console.

Comment: @user2951100 No, your browser's console. E.g. in Firefox, `ctrl+shift+k` (web console) or `ctrl+shift+j` (browser console).

Comment: nope had no idea that was there. but it showed me what i was missing and i now have it working. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("lname").value;
```

There is no id "lname" ... but there is "Lname". Javascript is stopping at this error so rest of your code is not getting executed.

Comment: even after fixing this  it still wont display

Answer (score 0):

Because your Id for last name is **"Lname"** and in javascript your are using **"lname"** which doesn't exist..

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to fix the alert function, you are missing close the
   function call.
2. The id used in the selector for Last Name is wrong.

PD: Please learn how to use the console of javascript. I didn't post the code because I think you need to figure out how to fix it even when I answer your question.